# How to show $A=\{(x,y)\in R^2:4x^2+9y^2=36\}$ is path connected and compact?

Tags: compactness, connectedness

let $A=\{(x,y)\in R^2:4x^2+9y^2=36\}$ . Show that A is path connected and compact.

my attempt: since $\frac {x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$  is elips. A is bounded and closed. so is compact. (by heine borel) How do we show it is path connected?

Comment: No need to use the fact that it is an ellipse to prove compactness. Use the fact that $F(x,y)=4x^2+9y^2-36$ is continuous and hence $F^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. Also use that $x^2,y^2 \leq F(x,y)+36$ to prove the zero set is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a path between two points, and you will have shown that the set is path connected.

Note that the parameterization
$$
x = 3 \cos t; \quad y = 2 \sin t; \quad t \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Yields a path through the entire space.  Use this to "connect" any two points.

**Alternatively:** $A$ is the continuous image of $S^1$ under some map (which you should find).  Since continuous maps preserve path connectedness, it suffices to note (or show) that $S^1$ is path connected.